# How to properly test node-red nodes?

Tags: unit-testing, node-red

I'm developing a node-red node, and I'd like to know the best or intended way to test those nodes. I've been looking at some other nodes, and they look to depend on a peer installation of node-red itself and use the "helper.js" to load those nodes. I was expecting to have a more "unit-level" testing perhaps mocking the node-red.

Comment: You'll do much better asking this on the Node-RED mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) than here.

Comment: The debug node in the node red help you to test your functionality and data at each node.[please check with node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC9H6.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the way that the core nodes are tested, this should give you some ideas.

There is also an effort underway to extract the [test harness from core and make it available for everyone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-test-helper). You should also check out the [Node-RED WIKI which contains some information on testing](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Testing).

In general, it looks like you will need to run your node in an embedded version of Node-RED. Running NR using your chosen test tool.